# Keep unique values with only 1 instance

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, unique

I have the following dataset:

```
    Col_A   Amounts
0   A      100
1   B      200
2   C      500
3   D      100
4   E      500
5   F      300
```

The output I am trying to achieve is to basically remove all values based on the "Amounts" column which have a duplicate value and to keep only the rows where there is **one unique instance** of a value.

Desired Output:

```
    Col_A   Amounts
1   B      200
5   F      300
```

I have tried to use the following with no luck:

```
df_1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Amounts'])
```

This removes the duplicates, however, it still keeps the values which have occurred more than once.

Using the pandas `.unique` function also provides a similiar undesired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need `keep=False` for remove all duplicates per `Amounts` column:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Amounts'], keep=False))
  Col_A  Amounts
1     B      200
5     F      300
```

Comment: Thank you - weirdly enough it works on this smaller 'example' dataset here in the post but when I do it on my practical df it returns an empty [] - is there any reason for this?

Comment: @Rip_027 - Sure, it means all `Amounts` are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Less straight forward than the previous answer, but if you want to be able keep the rows that appear *n* times, you could use `value_counts()` as a mask, and keep only the rows that appear exactly / at least / less than *n* times:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = { 'Col_1': ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
        'Amounts': [100, 200, 500, 100, 500,300]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

n=1

mask = df.Amounts.value_counts()
df[df.Amounts.isin(mask.index[mask.lt(n+1)])]
```

outputs:

```py
  Col_1  Amounts
1     B      200
5     F      300
```